# KDE Dolphin not preserving modified date of files when copying to samba share

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba, cifs, dolphin-file-manager

This is my first post here, but I've been an avid reader. I have not been able to resolve this on my even after reading a lot of articles on the matter.

I am using kubuntu 21.10 at the moment, but I have experienced this since I first installed it, probably with 20.04. When I try to move/copy a file from any disk in my pc to a samba share the modified dates are not preserved. They seem to be copied for a moment but then immediately change to "now".

The samba share is set on an RPi4. This is my /etc/samba/smb.conf file:

```
[MyBook]
path = /media/MyBook
writeable = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
public = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```

This is my fstab file to mount the share through cifs:

```
//192.168.1.14/MyBook /media/MyBook cifs credentials=.smbcredentialsRPi4,iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.mount-timeout=30,_netdev 0 0
```

I am able to read/write the folders as expected, but when copying files the timestamps are not preserved. This is only happening to me from the kubuntu install. I also have a separate partition with ubuntu and ubuntu-mate, this does not happen when copying from there to the samba share. The weird part is that I used the exact same file in the three installations. When copying from my Windows partition, it also preserves the timestamps, so it seems to be a kubuntu-only issue and not how the samba share is set up on the RPi4. This also happens not only with Dolphin but with other file managers - I tried Nemo and Nautilus and they do not preserve the timestamps in my kubuntu setup.

To show what happens, I copied a test file from a local disk to the samba share. The modified file on the original file is 10/03/2018, but the copied file's modified date is "now".

[Test file in local pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jb1a.png)

[Test file in samba share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIYKo.png)

Strangely enough, this does not happen when I use the samba address smb://192.168.1.14/MyBook/test/ as it does preserves the modified date. And if see the file from the mountpoint, it does show the correct modified date.

[samba address preserves the modified date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P14JF.png)

My guess is that it has something to do with how the mountpoint was created, or cifs itself.

This is how the mountpoint looks with ls

```
chris@operarum:~$ ls -l /media/ | grep MyBook
drwxrwxrwx   2 chris chris    0 mar 31 22:32 MyBook
```

This is the output from the RPi4:

```
pinas@rpi4:~ $ ls -l /media | grep MyBook
drwxrwxrwx  22 root root 4096 Mar 31 22:32 MyBook
```

I also tried with using a root account to mount the cifs, but the results are the same. What do you think it could be?

Answer (score 0):

I've been chewing on this one now for a while and it seems that it is caused by some weird bug which happens only NOT in 1 combination I found accessible from the command line.

The solution is to add an extra option to the mount command: vers=2.0 (which forces version 2.0 of the SMB protocol) AND NOT use fstab. Instead you could use a systemd unit file to mount the share.

HOW TO:
First, remove the fstab line or put a # in front of it.

Then, execute following command:

```
sudo nautilus /etc/systemd/system
```

In the Nautilus window, create a file, call it mountnas.service and fill it with following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount share
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.service

[Service]
ExecStart=mount -t cifs -o credentials=.smbcredentialsRPi4,iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.mount-timeout=30,_netdev,vers=2.0 "//192.168.1.14/MyBook" "/media/MyBook"
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save the file and execute following commands:

```
sudo systemctl start mountnas.service
sudo systemctl enable mountnas.service
```

Then it should work, also after reboot.

I noticed the problem too in Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 on the regular Gnome version, but for some reason not on Fedora. I suppose that Ubuntu uses another version of smb which creates this problem. The strange thing is that it works OK in default Ubuntu when trying to connect to the file share through Nautilus.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have tried this steps and get the same results as the ones I had when mounting through fstab. Made sure I used vers=2.0, but still. It seems to really be cifs.

Comment: I also tried with the the ubuntu mate partition and the issue does not exist there. Cifs version on mate was 6.11, tried downgrading the cifs version in kubuntu and the issue is still the same. I had also created a bug report in KDE https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452210